# Parity IPC direct connect

Tags: parity, json-rpc, ubuntu, ipc

Before Parity I used Geth, and made requests like:

`echo '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["latest", false],"id":1}' | nc -NU geth.ipc`

and It worked!
In Parity **v2.7.2** and Ubuntu 18.06 i tried to do it in the same way:

`echo '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["latest", false],"id":1}' | nc -NU jsonrpc.ipc`

But has no stdout. I tried several methods, but no one was success.
in `config.toml` I has this:

```
[ipc]
disable = false
path = "$HOME/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/jsonrpc.ipc"
apis = ["web3", "eth", "pubsub", "net", "parity", "parity_pubsub", "parity_accounts", "traces", "rpc", "shh", "shh_pubsub"]
```

Why I have silent stdout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be the `-N` parameter for the `nc` command

I was able to reproduce with the same request. According to `man nc`, `-N` shuts down the connection after input EOF. That's likely the reason why no output.

Removing `-N` (i.e. `nc -U jsonrpc.ipc`)gives the correct result in my test.